# JavaFx slow startup with XFCE

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, xfce

I have developped an JavaFX app.

I would to run my app in a XFCE desktop manager.

My problem it's that, my app takes a long time to start (approximately 30 seconds).

After several tests and measurements, I realized that my problem was from desktop manager because with lightdm on the same system, my app start in 10 seconds.

Do you have an idea why it's very slow with XFCE ?

And do you have any ideas about how to improve JavaFX startup performances ?

Thank you in advance !

### Infos

I run my app on Raspberry Pi 3B+ with YOCTO build OS (meta-raspberry / distro : poky).

I use OpenJFX version 11 (for aarch64).

I use OpenJDK version 11.

Comment: Lightdm is a display manager and Xfce a desktop environment, you're comparing apple and oranges. Try a different DE, e.g. Gnome, Mate, Cinnamon, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this difference.